# How can I create a simple javaScript dependency report?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using Visual Studio Code and developing a classic `html/css/javascript` web page. I've split up the javaScript files (ES6+) to provide structure and maintainability.  eg. main.js, happy.js, sad.js, whoCares.js, etc. I have used madge to generate some nice little svg graphs but these only display file level dependencies. I'm really looking for the next simple step up from this and json output will be good. One structure is just to list the javaScript files with the other js files they are dependent on - but for each file dependency, the names and types of the dependencies would be listed (see below example).

Can anyone suggest a script that will run against a directory (eg. ./js), find the files and report on the dependencies in the following manner?

```json
{
  "happy.js": {
    "main.js": {
      "exports": [
        {
          "name": "Smile",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "name": "Laugh",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "name": "happyPlaces",
          "type": "array"
        },
        {
          "name": "smileSize",
          "type": "constant"    
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sad.js": {
    "whoCares.js": {
      "exports": [
        {
          "name": "Confused",
          "type": "function"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "whoCares.js": {
    "main.js": {
      "exports": [
        {
          "name": "Shrug",
          "type": "function"
        },
        {
          "name": "placesToHide",
          "type": "array"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried a different options but I end up with way too much unhelpful output. What I want is simple and concise.

Comment: "*I have tried a different options but I end up with way too much unhelpful output*" - can you show what you tried, please? If you've already done the hard stuff (loading, parsing, constructing import/export maps, analysing dependencies) then it should be relatively simple to filter out the unhelpful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**dependency-tree** on npm does a good job of picking up dependencies of a file.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-tree

The example given (simplified) is:

`npm install -g dependency-tree`

`dependency-tree --directory=path/to/code/folder entryFile.js`

I used a modified form: **sxy-dependency-tree**. I developed this because dependency-tree was failing in a certain scenario, something to do with exports mapping IIRC. I don't think this will affect you.

**dependency-tree** doesn't return exports as far as I know. You could code that up yourself by using the **dependency-tree** JS API and importing the module dynamically, and then grabbing the keys from the imported object

`Object.keys(await import ('./module.js')) /// ['default', 'foo', 'bar']`